# how do i removed orphan linked material

Tags: materials, linked-data, data-blocks

I have two materials that I linked from another file  and I can't figure out how to delete them.[image: screen capture of locked materials] As you can see, both HairMix and VariableMaterial show LF in the search box. They do not go away when I close and reopen, because of the F state. How do I remove them?  [edited in response to a comment pointing out that the original question was invalid because I had misunderstood L to mean locked, rather than linked.]

Comment: The icon with the arrow means that the materials are linked, so you may have accidentally linked them instead of appended them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the material by right-clicking on it and selecting `delete` from the pop-up menu. This won't affect them in the other file, it just removes them from the one you are working on.

[image: video of deleting orphaned blender material]